# How do i pass a variable to all flask routes once?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So I have this Flask app that I need a pass a particular user to all routes as all pages in the app will be needing the particular user to render templates. I don't want to pass the user as it's normal done

```
return render_template('index.html',user=user)
```

Because I'd have to repeat the same thing for all routes in the render_templates.
Please how can I do this?

Comment: Where does the variable `user` originates from or where does the variable is set? inside the function or globally?

Comment: The user is actually global since it's imported. The issue how to send it across all pages via the render_template function. More like a default argument for render_template

Comment: you can use global var, which are automatically available in templates
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/templates/#the-base-layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so by creating a custom render template function using the following implementation

```py
from flask import render_template as real_render_template
from yourapp import user  # Import the user variable or set it

def render_template(*args, **kwargs):
    return real_render_template(*args, **kwargs, user=user)
```

it can also be done via `functools.partial`:

```py
from flask import render_template as real_render_template
from yourapp import user  # Import the user variable or set it
from functools import partial

render_template = partial(real_render_template, user=user)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a variable to all routes/pages/templates. You can use sessions in flask

```
from flask import Flask,session
[...]
session['x'] = user
```

Now you can use it anywhere in the code, templates using session['x']

In templates

```
{{session['x']}}
```

Comment: Will the session variable be available in the templates file automatically? For instance the url_for function is that way due to jinja2 config with flask

Comment: Yes once you define in flask it will be available. You need to define a secret_key too.